# Unable to add bitmap to stage

Tags: createjs

It seems I do it by the book, but it doesn't work. What on earth is wrong with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv-se">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/soundjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function init() {
            var stage = new createjs.Stage("stage");
            stage.canvas.width = 1200;
            stage.canvas.height = 871;

             var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
             queue.on("complete", handleComplete, this);
             queue.loadManifest([
                 {id: "myImage", src:"images/image.jpg"}
             ]);
             function handleComplete() {
                 var myImage = queue.getResult("myImage");

                 stage.addChild(myImage);
             }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">
    <canvas id="stage"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

All I get is this error message: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `createjs.Bitmap`  object out of the loaded image, add it to the stage and update the stage afterwards:

```
var myImage = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("myImage"));
stage.addChild(myImage);
stage.update();
```